# Probability question with dice

Tags: probability

Three standard dice are rolled and the numbers thrown are added. what is the probability of getting a sum of 15?

Comment: How would you approach this question? Do you have any solution-plan in mind?

Comment: Unfortunately not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't see any easier way than going over all options and summing the probabilities:

Probability $\frac{3!}{6^3}=\frac{1}{36}$:

4,5,6

Probability $\frac{3}{6^3}=\frac{1}{72}$:

3,6,6

Probability $\frac{1}{6^3}=\frac{1}{216}$:

5,5,5

All together, you get $\frac{5}{108}$.

Comment: $\frac{2!}{6^3}=\frac{1}{72}$?

Comment: $\frac{2!}{6^3} = \frac{1}{108} $ Giving you $\frac{1}{24}$ and not $\frac{5}{108}$

Comment: The number of variations of 3,6,6 is $\frac{3!}{2! \cdot 1!}=3$ not 2!

Comment: @robjohn - that was a mistyping. the probability is $\frac{1}{72}$, but I wrote $2!$ instead of $3$.

The final answer is true as well.

Comment: @RB: I noticed that you got the right answer, so I figured it was a typo.